# What is this thing sticking out in front of wings?

Tags: wing

I was wondering what this little stick on the wing was. My best guesses are an antenna or some sort of air speed measuring tube?

[image: Yak-9]

[image: Yak-3]

Comment: pitot tube placed there to get in in clean air (away from the prop).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct. That is the pitot tube (head), placed  there so that it is in undisturbed airflow. This location of pitot tube is found in othe aircraft too, like the Messerschmitt  Bf 109 G-2  as shown below.

[image: Pitot]

By Unknown - http://www.militaryimages.net/photopost/showphoto.php/photo/8212., Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2278317